# C++ Socket Server

Tags: c++

I need help
I'm trying to programm a server in C++
I can create the Socket, but I can't bind it to a IP and a PORT 
The error log can't dedect any error. I have tryed many ports, but it didn't work

```
int sock_val=-2,bind_val=-2,list_val=-2,acc_val=-2;
int port = 3502; 
struct sockaddr_in adress, client;

adress.sin_family = AF_INET;
adress.sin_port = htons(port);
adress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


Sock(sock_val);
Bind(sock_val,(sockaddr *)&adress,bind_val);
List(sock_val,list_val);
Acc(acc_val,sock_val,(sockaddr *)&client);

std::cin.get();

return 0;
}
void Sock(int sock_val)
{
   sock_val=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
   if (sock_val ==-1)
       Error("Starting Socket failed");
   else
       printf("Socket started");
}
void Bind(int sock_val, struct sockaddr *adress , int bind_val)
{

    bind_val=bind(sock_val,adress,sizeof(*adress));
    if (bind_val ==-1)
       Error("\nbind() failed");
    else
       printf("\nbind() succsesfull");

}
```

Comment: Your `Bind()` function doesn't have the good value for `sock_val`. You should return the socket descriptor value in your `Sock()` function.

Comment: You need operating system specific APIs to use sockets. C++11 don't know about sockets. You should use `perror`on error cases, and terminate your `printf` format strings with `\n`

Comment: You should learn about parameter passing and return values before trying to build a server in c++

Answer (score 0):

As it is, `sock_val` doesn't change after you called your `Sock()` function. You should return `sock_val` or pass it by reference:

```
int Sock()
{
    sock_val=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (sock_val ==-1)
    {
        Error("Starting Socket failed");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket started");
        return sock_val
    }
}
```

And it is the same for your `Bind()` function:

```
int Bind(int sock_val, struct sockaddr *adress)
{
    bind_val=bind(sock_val,adress,sizeof(*adress));
    if (bind_val ==-1)
    {
       Error("\nbind() failed");
       return -1;
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\nbind() succsesfull");
       return bind_val;
    }
}
```

And then, use your functions as below:

```
int sock_val = Sock();
if (sock_val != -1)
    int bind_val = Bind(sock_val, struct sockaddr *adress);
```

Comment: If have edited my code like this, but it doesn't work

Comment: @DanielLauss Do you get any error ? Does one of your function return `-1` somewhere ? Did you also change your `List()` and your `Acc()` functions ?